# How to quickly split transaction between two accounts in GnuCash?

Tags: macros, gnucash

Here's something that I do frequently in GnuCash:

1. Import transactions for my checking account
2. Most transactions are automatically mapped to an expense account
3. For transactions that I agreed to split with someone, edit the transaction so the amount for the expense account is split in two and assign the remaining half to another account (leaving the amount withdrawn from my checking account unchanged)

How can I quickly assign half of an expense to another specific account like this?

Comment: Just enter the half owed to you to a liability account (use the same liability account all the time). Clear the liability account when you receive the money.

Comment: @John Unless I'm misunderstanding you, my question is how to do that quicker.

Comment: I just put the liability account under the same expense account in the one transaction. I cannot do it quicker than that.

Comment: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/150768/possible-to-split-a-transaction-already-in-the-generic-import-transaction-mat/